# Python multithread causes console errors (can not type)

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, ubuntu

I've some code like

```
import os
import threading

class pixels (object):
    def myfunction(self, param1, param2):
        fileImage = str(name) + "_" + str(x) + ".jpg"
        os.system('ffmpeg -i "' + sub + '" -ss 00:00:' + str(timeFrame) + ' -loglevel panic -vframes 1 "' + fileImage + '"')
        somecode....
        os.remove(fileImage)

class otherClass (object):
    def myCallingFunction ():
        params1 = "example1"
        params2 = "example2"
        for i in someArray:
            task1= threading.Thread(target=pixels.myfunction, args=(params1, params2 ))
                task1.start()
```

before exit i've:

```
while threading.active_count() > 1:
            sleep(1)
```

Well, if i change the way to call the pixels.myfunction to without multithreading, it works, but slower. But with multithreading, the console after execution looks locked, you can type but don't see anythng (but it's writed!, yo can press enter after type some command and works, but you can't see what you types), do you have any idea of what could be the problem?

Comment: Not sure that target=pixels.myfunction is correct.

Comment: Yes, that part seems a bit odd, as myfunction is not a class method. Not sure how this would or could work.

Comment: `ffmpeg` reads commands from the console, so you have two applications competing for input on the same terminal. Try adding the `-nostdin` option to the ffmpeg command.

Comment: thanx, but didn't work, the execution works because functions after that ones works and prints the info, but only that problem is bothering me...

Comment: The code exposed is only a example because i've 800 lines of code, and it's too much to paste here..., The code works but not as fine as i want because that problemn with the console...